# Print only twelve characters from user submitted string in Java

Tags: java, input, printing, limit

I have a user input their name as a string and then the name is printed out onto the screen. How can i limit what is printed to only 12 characters so that a user cannot type an insanely long name? Here is my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your player name: ");
    String name= input.next();
    System.out.print("\n" + name + " has started the game\n");
```

Comment: how about you go back and accept some of the answers to your previous questions

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
String name = input.next();
name = name.length() > 12 ? name.substring(0, 11) : name;
```

and accept some of your previous answers.

Comment: Cool :) Please click on the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
public static void main (String[]args){
String s = new String();
        String n = new String();
        s = "ya ali madad";
        if (s.length() > 10) {
            n = s.substring(10, 12);
        }
        System.out.println("String s:" + s);
        System.out.println("String n:" + n);}}
```

Comment: suppose that you have many charters put them in one string then cut off the initial string into several pieces each piece will have a total length of 10  same as the above code